# Is there an SQLite database viewer tool in Eclipse?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using Eclipse for Android programming. Is there a tool for view an SQLite database in the emulator?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See blog post *[Browse an Android Emulator SQLite Database in Eclipse](http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse)*.

Comment: This made my life about 1000 times easier.

Comment: lovely.. made my life easier

Comment: Important Note: You won't be able to view the content of `Data` folder if you are developing on an unrooted phone. In that case use emulator to get the DB file.

Answer (score 9):

[Eclipse Plugin for Sqllite](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

Comment: All the images in that article are no longer online, so the article is not too helpful at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below steps:

1. Download [the .jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomquestoidsqlitebrowser120jar.htm) file
2. Place the plugin .jar file in your Eclipse plugins folder (e.g. /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins)
3. Restart Eclipse
4. Start up an Android Emulator with debugging in Eclipse
5. Switch to the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse
6. Go to the 'File Explorer' tab to locate your device's database file
7. Navigate to: e.g. 'data -> data -> com.myproject -> databases -> myproject
8. Open the database file in Questoid (see screenshot)
9. Switch to the 'Questoid SQLite Browser' tab that appears (mine appears next to LogCat by default)
10. Switch to the 'Browse Data' sub tab
    Select your table from the drop down menu
    Browse your data here and onward into the digital sunset

[Refer link](http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

follow below way -

1. download [SQLITE MANAGER JAR](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91846918/CoderzHeaven%20images/SQLite%20Manager%20Plugin/com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar) .
2. put the jar file into your **eclipse/dropins/** folder.

if(ubuntu user)

you can find your dropins folder at **usr/share/eclipse/dropins**
if you don't have permission to paste file at location
then opent your terminal (ctrl+alt+T) and type command **sudo nautilus**
then press enter the new window will open then you can paste the jar at the **dropins** folder

3. now restart the eclipse
4. go to DDMS
5. go to file explorer
6. browse your database file at **data -> data -> com.myproject -> databases -> myproject.db**
7. then you will se a database manager icon at to of file explorer
8. by clicking this you can see all of your data tables.

to know more follow [LINK](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

Thanks.