# How to pass agruments in method from class to another class?

Tags: android, sqlite

In below given code I need to delete one by one contact data from database of SQLlite. 
For this I write a method in Database Handler.java class. 
But during using this method in Main AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity.java class I have problem in passing arguments.(Where I write a comment "I feel a problem here").

And how can I trace all the save contacts in database to check that It is present or not. I need to show a pop up massage on screen if contact(data) is present in data base?

This is android AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity.java class

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
   final EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3); 
   Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str1 = editText.getText().toString();
        String str2 = editText2.getText().toString();   




    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity.this);


    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    //  db.addContact(new Contact(str1, str2));
    //db.addContact(new Contact(str2, "9199999999"));
    //db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "9522222222"));
    //db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "9533333333"));

    // Reading all contacts

    db.deleteContact( "What should i need to pass here"???)   //Here I feel problem

    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
            // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);

    }

    }
   });


   }
}
```

This is a DatabaseHandler.java class

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your OWN documentation, you should pass a Contact object check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) link (I assume you copied the code without really understanding what you doing - for that a word of advice, you cant really learning by copying in contrary to learning by doing..), to check out your database content using sqlite reader plugins for eclipse or import the db to your computer using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.browser.app) or check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966477/is-there-any-sqlite-database-viewer-tool-in-eclipse) SO thread or [this](http://blog.kwyps.com/2011/07/how-to-view-sqlite-database-on-your.html) guide

Comment: I just need to know how to use deletecontact() method in AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity.java class to delete contact? db.deletecontact( ????  Now what should i need to pass here ?

Comment: Some time we need to copy and paste when we have very less time to submit a project to client. By the way your are right "copy and paste kill programmer's skill".

Comment: I alreay wrote to you - a Contact object.
Lets say you created a new contact - 
    Contact myContact = new Contact();
    // Adding some data here for myContact //
in you delete contact you need to pass the 'myConteact' object